# Display data from DB - Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I need help in Laravel.

I need to list all VIEWS from db.

I have written this query in my **Controller**:

```
$reports = DB::select("Select TABLE SCHEMA", TRIM('r_all_' FROM TABLE_NAME) as viewname FROM       information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW' AND table_schema LIKE 'mprm_shared' AND TABLE_NAME     LIKE 'r_all_%'");
```

With this code I am getting all the views, but in my **Model** I have only this code:
protected $table = 'r_all_users';

With this code I can see the table only from this view: r_all_users.

What I need to change to display tables from All VIEWS, not only from r_all_users?

I need help in my code and I think it is good to ask this

Comment: You mean list of all tables?

Answer (score 0):

you can:
Lists all the tables in all databases

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
```

Lists all the tables in a particular database

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
      AND table_schema = 'your_database_name'
```

Comment: what I need to put in the Model?

Comment: in mvc architecture, every table has its own model you cant create a model that returns all the table. in order to get list of all the available tables you have to write raw query or use Schema::getAllTables(); @Martin

Comment: @Martin here is a link for mvc architecture https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-model-view-controller-pattern-mvc-architecture-and-frameworks-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel Schema method [`getAllTables()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php#L371)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

...

Schema::getAllTables();
```

It would return an array that contains all table names.